# Discord BOT Send DM to someone using the person ID's

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to send a DM to someone using their ID, i tried this code and it says `Instance of 'Client' has no 'get_user_info' member pylint(no-member)`

here's the code, i put this code on `@client.event` so it triggers when i say something to the BOT

```
    if message.content.lower() == 'dm':
        user = await client.get_user_info(user_id="USER'S ID")
        await client.send_message(user, "Your message")
```

I need help for this!

Comment: Try `fetch_user` instead? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `on_message`

```py
    if message.content.lower() == 'dm':
        user = await client.fetch_user(message.author.id) #you can also just type the id
        await user.send("Your message")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much!, this code works for me

```
if message.content.lower() == 'dm':
     user = await client.fetch_user(ID goes here)
     await user.send("Your message here")
```